# Get "ls -la" information with java

Tags: java, file, posix, ls

I was wondering if I can get an output like this with Java

[image]

That has to work under Linux, Windows and Mac; and if it's possible I prefer not to use `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: The methods are different for Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: Are you okay with writing JNI?  It seems like a lot more debt to build JNI for three (at least) platforms than to just call `Runtime.exec`...

Comment: Well, write  your own program in Java, using only portable code, that displays the output as desired. That should be easy using the new java.nio.file package

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Harlandraka [Java Tutorial NIO 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Comment: @Harlandraka [Another Example](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/jEdit/bsh/commands/dir.java.shtml) of unix-like directory listing implemented with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the metadata of a `File` object to get anything you need. Check the following link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

*Example:*

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

(This example was taken from the link I provided).

Hope this helps you

---

Checking the Java API, I find out that the data you need (size, attributes, etc.) are accesible through the `File` class methods. Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Notice that linux and mac are both Unix-like systems, and windows is not. Therefore, you won't be able to get all the file attributes you can expect to get on linux or mac in windows... but you can get the most important values

Comment: Ok thanks but what about getting file permissions, owner, user, group?

Comment: @Harlandraka check the link I provided; it has a section titled "POSIX File Permissions". But you must be aware that Windows is not POSIX

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, now i have only another question, how do i format permissions to have output similar to ls -la? i.e. -rw-------

Comment: @Harlandraka append your values to a string... format them any way you want (maybe using the `java.text.NumberFormat` class) and concatenate them

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, because the output you want has *nix-only attributes "owner" and "group", which don't exist on Windows platforms. A java `File` doesn't have this information and that would be the only way to get file info without using `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: Well ok but for example FileZilla Server works only on Windows and it emulates linux to get file permissions, there must be a way to do that, maybe with JNI or maybe not, but ther must be a way to do that... Any suggestions?

Comment: You wrote the question... if you don't want to use `Runtime.exec()` you can't get it. If it were me, I'd detect the system type then run the appropriate command for the platform  through `Runtime.exec()` and get what I need from the output

Comment: Runtime.exec is slow and i think it's not the proper way to do it, because Java is not platform dependent so there must be a way to do it, i'll check the solution that Barranka gave me.